# Dynamically changing Marionette template in LayoutView?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I have a parent class that looks something like:

#### Query Advanced

```
return Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
    template: template,
```

I have a subclass that extends this parent

```
return QueryAdvanced.extend({

    onBeforeShow: function(){
```

For my subclass, I have a custom template I want to use, but it is automatically using the `Query Advanced` template. How can I override this?

Answer (score 0):

I simply added `template: template` in the subclass. Ezpz